# How do I play .swf GAMES on ubuntu?

Tags: games, flash

A lot of people say that you can do it on a browser, but it just appears on the download section. But I dont want to go through the trouble of fixing the browser and all that; plus, I dont want to use a browser. Is there a way to play .swf without having to use the browser? And I mean .swf GAMES, not movies. I say this because every other post has an answer for movies. Is there a program I can use, or even a command?

Im using ubuntu 17.04.

Thanks!

Comment: It will depend on some details of the swf application.  Can you provide an example of the swf application you're trying to use.  If you edit your question and add an swf example it'll make it convenient for someone reading your initial question to provide the best advice.  By the way, you are right about using the browser for swf files.  Google Chrome should work.

Comment: Have you looked at `flashplayer`, `swfplayer`, and `gnash`?

Answer (score 13):

Adobe hides this well, but there is a download of a standalone flash player on http://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/debug_downloads.html.

The [Flash Player Projector (64-bit)](https://fpdownload.macromedia.com/pub/flashplayer/updaters/32/flash_player_sa_linux.x86_64.tar.gz) works well for me; if you're a developer who wants to debug swf files, use the [Flash Player Projector content debugger (64-bit)](https://fpdownload.macromedia.com/pub/flashplayer/updaters/27/flash_player_sa_linux_debug.x86_64.tar.gz). Once downloaded, you need to open the file, extract the binary to a convenient place, and use something like `flashplayerdebugger assets/myfile.swf` from the command line.